# Browser refresh causes data loss jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, browser, refresh

I'm new to jquery mobile (and all web developpement) I'm trying to code a mobile web site, but I'm really stuck because of a problem... It might be easy to solve but I really tried everything that I could but it doesn't help

My problem is that whenever the user refreshes the page on the browser, he looses all the data added dynamicly with jquery...

I want to keep these data available because it's silly to loose everything on a refresh

Any help would be appreciated and I would be really thankful,, Have a nice day ! ;)

Comment: Google 'cookies' and 'web storage'

Comment: Hi mishik,, can you developpe a little bit your proposition please ?

Comment: You can either use cookies to store data that will persist after refresh, or web storage. Web storage is new and is not supported in all browsers, but provides greater flexibility than just cookies.

Comment: thkns ! And do you have an idea why I can not not my script after refreshing ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use cookies or local storage.

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.github.com/andris9/jStorage/master/jstorage.js"></script>
<script> /* $.jStorage is now available */ </script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/magnusburton/KkYdj/

http://www.jstorage.info/

Comment: Hi Magnus do you think it can resolve the problem... because further more I can't use my script jquery at all after refresh...